# UIButton not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIButton` dynamically created inside a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, I have set the button handler but the handler never gets called when the button is pressed.

Here is how I am creating the `UIButton` in the tap gesture:

```
 UIButton *uiButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[uiButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[uiButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 80, 25)];
[uiButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

And this is the Button Handler:

```
- (void)myButtonClick {
// button was tapped - do something
if(NULL) {

}

}
```

This has been EDITED:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

CGPoint touchPoint=[recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];



UIViewMenuItem *tempView = (UIViewMenuItem *)recognizer.view;
NSNumber *tag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tempView.tag];
NSString *idCat = [tempView getCatId];

NSLog(@"TAG %@",idCat);

//NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/MAMP/WHFC/SubCategories.php?categoryid//=%d", idCat]]];

NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"categoryid=%@",idCat];

// Create Data from request
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost:8888/MAMP/WHFC/SubCategories.php"]];
// set Request Type
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
// Set content-type
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
// Set Request Body
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
// Now send a request and get Response
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
// Log Response
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *err;

NSArray *arrCategoryList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];

const unsigned char *ptr = [data bytes];

for(int i=0; i<[data length]; ++i) {
    unsigned char c = *ptr++;
    NSLog(@"char=%c hex=%x", c, c);
}

self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *dictCategory in arrCategoryList)
{
    NSString *strCategoryId = [dictCategory objectForKey:@"CategoryId"];
    NSString *strCategoryName = [dictCategory objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"%@ : %@",strCategoryId,strCategoryName);

    Listing *listing = [[Listing alloc] init];
    listing.catId = strCategoryId;
    listing.name = strCategoryName;

    [self.data addObject:listing];


}

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIView *uiView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[uiView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480)];
[uiView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

viewController.view = uiView;

UINavigationBar *uiNavigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
[uiView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
[uiView addSubview:uiNavigationBar];

UIButton *uiButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[uiButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[uiButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 80, 25)];
[uiButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[uiNavigationBar addSubview:uiButton];

uiTableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] init];
[uiTableView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 480)];
uiTableView1.dataSource = self;
uiTableView1.delegate = self;

[uiView addSubview:uiTableView1];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];



//Do stuff here...
}

- (void)myButtonClick {
// button was tapped - do something
if(NULL) {

}

}
```

Comment: Where do you adding it to a view? What is the purpose of `if (NULL)`?

Comment: (1) Does the button show up? (I assume "yes") (2) You have not forgotten to add the button to a parent view, right? (I assume "no, you have not forgotten") (3) What's the deal with `if (NULL)`? The code inside that conditional is never executed.

Comment: the if(NULL) is just there to put a break point in so that i know its going into the method

Comment: the button is placed in another view not the parent view

Comment: Did you try creating it with `+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType`?

Comment: no i have edited the code that shows how i have done this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your gesture recognizer is catching the touch and therefor is never reaching the button. To let the button get the event you have to set the delegate of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and implement something like this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ((touch.view == mybutton)||(touch.view == anyOtherButton)) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`Biggest mistake` you have `made` is you `used` `forControlEvents` is `UIControlEventTouchDown`. Your `requirement` is `different` here.`

**Solution** : It should be `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` as `button` gets `clicked` when touched.

`Replace` below line with yours

```
[uiButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**EDIT** : Also `superview` of `button` is out of `bound` ie `y` is `480` it should be `0`

`Replace` below line with yours

```
[uiView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

Comment: Thanks but did not work, could it be because there is another view under the view that contains the button?

Comment: @redoc01 check now if it finds your solution.

Comment: i set that 480 to 0 and still no luck